# How to implement a Spread out edge in CSS

Tags: css

Please how can I implement the white background shape below in CSS?

[image]

Here is what I have tried but to no success:

```
#curved-corner-bottomleft,
#curved-corner-bottomright,
#curved-corner-topleft,
#curved-corner-topright {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#curved-corner-bottomleft:before,
#curved-corner-bottomright:before,
#curved-corner-topleft:before,
#curved-corner-topright:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Any insights would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: We need to see your HTML. Also, it looks like you have _divitis_ going on: you should not need to have excessive wrapper `<div>` or `<span>` elements.

Comment: Why aren't you using image borders instead? You can use a `data:` URI containing complex SVG artwork.

Comment: You shouldn't need an image or extra elements for this. Have you investigated  using clip-path? It could help you get rid of extra elements which are there just for decoration not content.